# vertical align bottom + inline block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div class = "box">
  <div class="box1 item"></div>
  <div class="box2 item"></div>
  <div class="box3 item"></div>
  <div class="box4 item"></div>
</div>
```

box1 -> box4 has a display of inline-block.

```
.box {
   min-height: 403px;
}
.item { 
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   max-width: 20%;
}
```

For some reason, I cannot vertically align the divs with class "item" to the bottom of the box container. Does anyone know why?

Each element with class name item is part of a carousel that bleeds to the next page. Meaning each page shows 3.5 images.

Comment: How is class bottom defined?

Comment: _"For some reason, I cannot vertically align the divs with class "bottom""_ No elements at `html` at Question have `className` `"bottom"`?

Comment: Please explain what layout you are trying to do. Looks like a typical `XY Problem`.

Comment: I want to vertically align to the bottom of box container the items with class name "item"

Comment: Can it be `height` https://jsfiddle.net/rydbbzbh/ rather than `min-height`?

Comment: The problem with CSS `flex box`is that it not yet working in all browsers (without considering IE9 lower versions). The best compatible way is to use Javascript/jQuery with it. you can also use with CSS something like `position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;` in a container.

Comment: position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; Will not do that. The inline property is loost that way. 
Using jQuery for this is over bloated. When you want this work also in old browsers, you have to use tables.

Answer (score 4):

`vertical-align: bottom` aligns inline-level elements to the bottom of their line box.

```css
.box {
  min-height: 403px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item { 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1 item">1<br />1<br />1<br />1</div>
  <div class="box2 item">2<br />2<br />2</div>
  <div class="box3 item">3<br />3</div>
  <div class="box4 item">4</div>
</div>
```

If you want to align them to the bottom of the container, you need more advanced layouts, like CSS tables, or flexbox:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height: 403px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item { 
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1 item">1<br />1<br />1<br />1</div>
  <div class="box2 item">2<br />2<br />2</div>
  <div class="box3 item">3<br />3</div>
  <div class="box4 item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is I have 5 images in a carousel, and I don't want all the images to fit on the page. People can click next to see the remaining images

Comment: @Jasmine But how is that related to the question or my answer? If it's not related, you can [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: CSS `flex box`is that it not yet working in all browsers (without considering IE9 lower versions)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Flexbox is supported by 94.1% used browsers according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (adding vendor prefixes). If you want more support, there are CSS tables.

Comment: No need of tables, There is others ways with CSS than css flex box. But your solution is nice anyways… just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Oriol is the right one. But if you want to be save with old browsers, use table instead.

One solution could be:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class = "box">
    <div class="box1 item">a</div>
    <div class="box2 item">s</div>
    <div class="box3 item">a</div>
    <div class="box4 item">p</div>
  </div>
</div>  

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 403px;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.item { 
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   max-width: 20%;
}
```